# need a dictionary like this

Tags: python, python-3.x

i want to use an ordered dictionary which its iterate action looks like list

```
seq.append(2)
seq.append(3)
seq.append(1)

print(seq)# the list should be 2,3,1

dic[2] = '22222'
dic[3] = '333333'
dic[1] = '111111'
print(dic)# should be {2:'22222',3,'333333',1:'111111'} not {1...2...3}
```

i don't know if there is already a class in python standard library.or i need a list to keep the order,that's would be too complicated, tell me the simplest way you know how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Python [`OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) collection will help you here:

> "dict subclass that remembers the order entries were added"